# Searching for Column Values in another Worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to search for Values of Column A in Worksheet 1 through Columns F:FV in Worksheet 2 for matches.

So far I've used:

=IF(ISNA(LOOKUP(2^15,FIND(A2,Searches!$F:$FV),Searches!$F:$FV)),"NOT FOUND","FOUND")

Excel is telling me it ran out of resources attempting to calculate this formula. Is there anything I can do to remedy this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
Based on conversation below, previous solution did not meet actual needs. Left undeleted for conversation to continue.

Comment: Also, if you are only looking for the existence of the item 2^15 rather than a specific result, then you don't need to provide the result vector in the lookup formula. That will save some unecessary processing.

Comment: I did not use an array formula. I used the specific parameters of F:FV because that's where my longest row ends. So do you suggest I expend those parameters or using an "indirect" function? I do not know how to use indirect function is that is indeed your advice

Comment: Do you really mean F:FV, or are you trying to look at the single column F:F? See my edit if you are only looking at F:F.

Comment: Yes F:FV, as in about ~150 Columns. They are in 150 Columns because I was having trouble searching through the data while it was in one column separated by commas. Should I revert back to just in one Column with certain cells containing enormous amounts of data (~150 IDs separated by commas)?

Comment: 1 more clarification - do you want exact values only, or do you want to show anything that contains your search string, even if that cell contains other items? ie: show a hit for "hi" when "hiya" is in a cell? And are you looking for the location of a matching cell, or just confirmation that there is a match? Or just a confirmation of the number of times there is a match?

Comment: I'd like exact matches. I know for exact you put "*   *" around the search string. Also I'd like the location of the match, and to further clarify I know there will be multiple matches, so is it possible to get multiple results or will it only return me the first time the match is found?

Comment: What do you want to do with the matches once found? You can do what you want without VBA, but it will be messy and if you want to do something consistent with the matched cells (like delete every cell which matches) then I would suggest a VBA macro.

Comment: I will use the matches for analysis. If it matches it means the searched ID was also executed, from which I will calculate the time to execution from a search to a trade. I have already matched the Users, however my issue is also that it returns me only the location of the 1st match of the user, not every occurrence. I'm essentially doing the same thing with IDs where my current question is.

Comment: You need to provide more details on what your worksheet looks like, and how you want it to act. Please edit your question to include more details.